# Flex 3: How can I see if a variable exists

Tags: apache-flex, validation, variables

I'm getting the "Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference." error on my application.  Is there a function I can use to detect this before it causes an error... maybe something like:

```
isValid(variableName);
```

I know there's one, because i've used it before, but i can't remember what it is right now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296861/test-if-an-object-is-defined-in-actionscript

Same question right there

Comment: I voted to close due to the duplicate question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296861/test-if-an-object-is-defined-in-actionscript

Comment: Nope... this isn't the same.  There's different way. Ugh, I'll keep on looking for it.  I'll post it when i find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess: [hasOwnProperty](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html#hasOwnProperty%28%29)

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, a null object maps to a Boolean false.
suppose:

```
var x:ArrayCollection; //uninitialised
if(x) {
    Alert.show("X");
} else {
    Alert.show("NOT X");
}
```

Above code will show an alert saying NOT X because a null variable maps to false

However, if you want to check whether an object has a property with a particular name, try

```
var o:MyObject=new MyObject();
if(o.hasOwnProperty("something")) {
    Alert.show(o.something);
} else {
    Alert.show("Something undefined");
}
```

now if there is a property called "something" on o, EVEN IF ITS VALUE IS null, it will go into if()...
otherwise it will go into else.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `if` statement will work.

```
if (myVariable)
{
  //do something
}
```

**UPDATE:** After looking at the code that's causing the error, my guess is that either `wholeProject[j]` is null or `wholeProject[j].wholePosition` is null. Try something like this:

```
if (wholeProject[j] && wholeProject[j].wholePosition)
{
  for (var k:int = 0; k < wholeProject[j].wholePosition.length; k++)
}
```

Comment: @Brds Can you post the line of code that's causing the error?

Comment: for (var k:int = 0; k < wholeProject[j].wholePosition.length; k++)

Comment: @Brds I just updated my answer based on the code you posted. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quite simple.  Use a try/catch construct with the (err:)
For example, I use this to surround parsing code that can generate errors. "Error" means any error.

```
try { relation.parseObject(XMLObject["relation"],source); } 
catch (err:Error) {tr.output(mN + "bad relation " + err)};
```

You would do this:

```
try {
newvalue = variableName;
}
catch (error:ReferenceError) { <do something> }
```